# Pushing a new view using UIBarButtonItem

Tags: view, uinavigationbar, push, uibarbuttonitem

I'm a relatively new developer.  I'm trying to push a new view to the screen when the user selects one of the barButtonItems without it being a navigation controller.  I know how to do this for selecting a cell in a table, but when I try the same techniques on the barButton, they don't work.  Can anybody help me?